# has anyone figured out a way to use the back-facing camera on android in any browser with getusermedia?

Tags: html, camera

I can’t seem to find the settings anywhere. I also tried searching the phone to set front-facing as default but had no luck. I’m using an xiaomi 1s if that helps.sorry ,my english is poor